# KnockoutJS select option value

Tags: knockout.js, jquery-ui-selectmenu

I'm trying to disable one select HTML element based on value from another select HTML element using KnockoutJS

HTML code for that part looks like:

```
<label for="searchBy">Search by:</label>
<select id="searchBy" name="searchBy" tabindex="1" data-bind="options: searchBy, value: selectedSearchBy, optionsText: 'searchBy', optionsValue: 'searchBy'"></select>

<label for="searchMethod">Search method:</label>
<select id="searchMethod" name="searchMethod" tabindex="2" data-bind="options: searchMethod, value: selectedSearchMethod, optionsText: 'searchMethod', optionsValue: 'searchMethod', disable: searchByDOB"></select>
```

and related KonckutJS code:

```
this.searchByDOB = ko.observable(false);

this.searchBy = ko.observableArray([{searchBy: 'Name', value: 'name'},{searchBy: 'Date of Birth', value: 'dob'},{searchBy: 'User ID', value: 'id'}]);

this.selectedSearchBy = ko.observable();
this.searchMethod = ko.observableArray([{searchMethod: 'beginning with', value: 's%'},{searchMethod: 'containing', value: '%s%'},{searchMethod: 'ending with', value: '%s'}]);
this.selectedSearchMethod = ko.observable();

this.selectedSearchBy.subscribe(function(latest) {
  console.log("Search by: " + this.selectedSearchBy().value);
    if(this.selectedSearchBy().value == 'dob')
    {
      this.searchByDOB = ko.observable(true);
    }

}, this);
```

but what I'm getting is that `this.selectedSearchBy().value` is `undefinied`

What i have missing? Should I change logic to on change event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `.value` property; it is this one that gives the undefined error.

Just read the value via `this.selectedSearchBy()`.

Also write to a property via `this.searchByDOB(true)` instead of a value assignment.

**EDIT**

The subscribe method must include both the enable `this.searchByDOB(true)` and disable `this.searchByDOB(false)` statements, otherwise the dropdown list stays disabled once disabled.

Also, only checking via `(this.selectedSearchBy() === 'dob')`  suffices.
(Prefere `===` over `==`, although it makes no difference here.)

```js
function ViewModel()
{

    this.searchByDOB = ko.observable(false);

    this.searchBy = ko.observableArray([
        {searchBy: 'Name', value: 'name'},
        {searchBy: 'Date of Birth', value: 'dob'},
        {searchBy: 'User ID', value: 'id'}
      ]);

    this.selectedSearchBy = ko.observable();
    
    this.searchMethod = ko.observableArray([
        {searchMethod: 'beginning with', value: 's%'},
        {searchMethod: 'containing', value: '%s%'},
        {searchMethod: 'ending with', value: '%s'}
        ]);
        
    this.selectedSearchMethod = ko.observable();

    this.selectedSearchBy.subscribe(function(latest) {
        var isSearchByDob = (this.selectedSearchBy() === 'dob');        
        this.searchByDOB(isSearchByDob);
        }, this
        );
}

var vm = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<label for="searchBy">Search by:</label>
<select id="searchBy" name="searchBy" tabindex="1" data-bind="options: searchBy, value: selectedSearchBy, optionsText: 'searchBy', optionsValue: 'value'"></select>

<label for="searchMethod">Search method:</label>
<select id="searchMethod" name="searchMethod" tabindex="2" data-bind="options: searchMethod, value: selectedSearchMethod, optionsText: 'searchMethod', optionsValue: 'value', disable: searchByDOB"></select>
```

Answer (score 2):

The first time your subscription fires is immediately when the page loads so there isn't a selection yet. selectedSearchBy is undefined just like it says so you can't call ".value" on it.

You can either give selectedSearchBy a default value that matches one of the options in your searchBy array, or you can check the value of selectedSearchBy before calling .value.

```
this.selectedSearchBy.subscribe(function(latest) {
    if(this.selectedSearchBy() && this.selectedSearchBy().value == 'dob')
    {
      this.searchByDOB = ko.observable(true);
    }
}, this);
```

Comment: I have tried both. First will return not defined on selection and second (listing above) is not working at all.

Answer (score 0):

Well, working solution is a combination of both answers.

First DOM elements were not set correctly to get proper values:

```
<label for="searchBy">Search by:</label>
<select id="searchBy" name="searchBy" tabindex="1" data-bind="options: searchBy, value: selectedSearchBy, optionsText: 'searchBy', optionsValue: 'value'"></select>

<label for="searchMethod">Search method:</label>
<select id="searchMethod" name="searchMethod" tabindex="2" data-bind="options: searchMethod, value: selectedSearchMethod, optionsText: 'searchMethod', optionsValue: 'value', disable: searchByDOB"></select>
```

then proper JS for that par:

```
this.selectedSearchBy =  ko.observable({searchBy: 'Name', value: 'name'});
```

...

```
       this.selectedSearchBy.subscribe(function(latest) {
            if(this.selectedSearchBy() && this.selectedSearchBy() == 'dob')
            {
                this.searchByDOB(true);
            }
        }, this)
```

Thanks goes to @JasonSpake and @pfx